# Ez-Vcard retrieval of email and address

Tags: parsing, vcf-vcard

There are inbuilt functions in getting the structuredname and formattedname. But for email there is no such method. I am using a maven project and i have added the dependency in the POM.xml.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.ez-vcard</groupId>
        <artifactId>ez-vcard</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.4</version>
</dependency>
```

vcard.getFormattedName().getValue()

is working fine and fetching the name.

```
vcard.getEmail().getValue()
```

is not working. Is there any library I am missing? or what is the method to fetch all the details from vcard.

I am using this for fetching the telephone details also and I always get null. Please advice.

```
for(Telephone tel: vcard.getTelephoneNumbers())
{
   String number=tel.getText();
}
```

Thanks
Arun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `getEmails()` method, like so:

```
for (Email email : vcard.getEmails()){
  String value = email.getValue();
}
```